# Raspberry Pi Coding

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

I plan on making a digital alarm clock with a raspberry pi, but the only language I'm familiar with is Java. I need to know if the Pi can run java, and if so, is it difficult to move the program over to it and make it run, or is it the same as writing a program for any other OS?

Also, will I need to install java on the Pi, or does it ship ready to run?

Comment: It's really too broad a question for StackOverflow and one that could be answered with a little research on the Web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi (normally) runs on Rasbian (which is built on top of Debian). This means that the Raspberry pi is running a version of Linux. On Linux to compile and run Java code you must first download a JDK. The Command to do this is `apt-get install default-jdk` (see https://wiki.debian.org/Java).
To compile a .java source you would then run `javac file.java` after compiling to run the program use `java file.class`